# Java RestTemplate hangs on 204 status code response

Tags: java, httprequest, resttemplate, rest-client, spring-web

I'm creating test framework and using RestTemplate class for HTTP request creation.

In general cases I use next code:

```
Response response = null;
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;

    try{
        responseEntity = getRest().exchange(url, httpMethod, httpEntity, String.class);
        response = new Response(
                responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue(),
                responseEntity.getStatusCode().getReasonPhrase(),
                responseEntity.getBody(),
                responseEntity.getHeaders()
        );
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e){
        response = new Response(
                e.getRawStatusCode(),
                e.getStatusText(),
                e.getResponseBodyAsString(),
                e.getResponseHeaders()
        );
    }
```

It works perfectly for all cases except DELETE HTTP method which receives 204 status code and empty body as a response.

Now, I have to reinitialize RestTemplate to fix it. But I hope that another way should exist.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you use HttpMethod.Delete for httpMethod and also try when you use delete to put as last parameter of exchange not String.class but Void.class.

I hope it help you.

Comment: I did this

if (httpMethod.matches("DELETE")){
                getRest().exchange(url, httpMethod, httpEntity, Void.class);
            }else {
                responseEntity = getRest().exchange(url, httpMethod, httpEntity, String.class);
            }

didn't help